# Taking the mean of one component of vectors in a list but leaving other components unchanged

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of 2D vectors ($x$ and $y$ coordinates).

The list is comprised by a row of vectors for a total of 500 rows. 
i.e., Row 1 is (1, y_values) to row 500 as (500, y_values).
The x component of each row is the same.  (1st row has all $x$ values as "1", 500th row has all $x$ values as "500').

I would like to take the mean of the $y$ values of each row, but keep the $x$ component the same so I can plot the mean on $y$ axis and keep the $x$ value the same.

Comment: Please show some small part of the dataset, or make up some data illustrating its structure.

Comment: Am I missing something? `Mean/@theData` should suffice....

Comment: If the components are all the same, then the mean of them is the same value.  Simply take the mean of the data.

Answer (score 2):

If your `data` looks like this:

```
SeedRandom[0]
data = Table[Transpose@{ConstantArray[i, 3], RandomReal[1, 3]}, {i, 5}]
```

> {{{1, 0.652468}, {1, 0.63307}, {1, 0.682813}}, {{2, 0.566352}, {2, 
>      0.935202}, {2, 0.976188}}, ....etc....}

[image]

Then simply

```
Mean /@ data
```

> {{1, 0.656117}, {2, 0.825914}, {3, 0.325704}, {4, 0.539612}, {5, 
>     0.617346}}

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Flatten /@ Transpose@{Range@5, RandomInteger[10, {5, 3}]};
data // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{#, Mean@{##2}} & @@@ data // MatrixForm
(* or *) {#[[1]], Mean@#[[2 ;;]]} & /@ data // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, using [@kglr's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) setup:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Flatten /@ Transpose@{Range@5, RandomInteger[10, {5, 3}]};

{First@#, Mean@Rest@#}\[Transpose] &[data\[Transpose]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: If `data` is a packed array, so is the output.

```
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[data, Real];
{First@#, Mean@Rest@#}\[Transpose] &[data\[Transpose]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(*  True  *)
```